# django blocktrans - add jquery variable

Tags: jquery, django, translation

I am trying to insert a jquery variable into a django blocktrans string. I am trying to display the size of an uploaded file in the django translation string.

I am not sure it is possible - I like to think so, but cannot work it out.

Here is my culled code:

```
$('#id_attachment_document').bind('change', function() {

        if (this.files[0].size > {{ max_attachment_file_size_kb_validation }}) {

            var user_file_size = this.files[0].size;  // declare variable of users file size.

            ....culled for brevity.

            {% blocktrans with user_file_size as user_file_size %}This file size is {{ user_file_size }} kB.{% endblocktrans %}');

    });
```

Comment: Think about when/where the django template tag is running and when/where your jQuery is running...

Comment: are you saying that the jquery is running client side and the django template is running server side? meaning that the above is not possible?

Comment: It should work...try this: var temp={% blocktrans %}"This file size is" + user_file_size + "kB"{% endblocktrans %}; alert(temp);

Comment: Django tags are server side, but all they do is change whatever you render...post therendered html, that can help.

Comment: cdvv778, thanks your suggestion worked.